# Optimisation problem with strange side conditions

Tags: optimization

I'm dealing with the following optimisation problem:
$$\min_{a \in H,\ b \in \mathbb{R}} F(a,b),$$
where $H$ is the solution space of another optimisation problem ($a$ is a real vector). I suppose as long as the space $H$ is not continuous there is no work around as to look at all the solutions $H$ and plug them in and then solving the original problem?